# Rails Carrierwave change uploaded file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How can I change in console uploaded file name without changing records in DataBase?

For example:

```
Photo.first.image.file 
 => #<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007fdeabefbd98 @file="/.../public/uploads/app/2/photo/3_venice.jpeg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil> 

Photo.first.image.file.exists?
=> false

Photo.first.image.file.file
=> "/.../public/uploads/app/2/photo/3_venice.jpeg"
```

My final aim to find file with some dependent name, like (without first symbol, model ID - 3): `venice.jpeg`

And rename it to needed name: `3_venice.jpeg`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution :)

```
Photo.find_each do |p|
    File.rename((p.image.file.file.split('/')[0...-1].join('/')+'/'+p.image.file.file.split('/').last.split('_')[1..-1].join('_')), p.image.file.file) if p.image.file.exists? == false
end
```